# Unable to loop through in mvc view razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am unable compare inside the foreach loop. This is the code below.

```
 @foreach (c3card.Dal.EDModel.tm_scrn_screen obj in tmgrp)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @obj.scrn_name
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.perm_details)
                        {
                            if (@obj.scrn_id == @item.scrn_id)
                            {
                                <tr> <td>@item.perm_read</td></tr>
                                <tr> <td>@item.perm_write</td></tr>

                                if (@item.perm_read == true)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber1" checked="checked" />
                                        </td>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber2" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                if (@item.perm_write == true)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>

                                            <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber1" checked="checked" />
                                        </td>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber2" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber1" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber2" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

This code I am not able to compare using if

```
if (@item.perm_read == true)
```

I am displaying value of @item.perm_read above and it return true but whn I compare it returns false. May I know why I am not able to compare?    @item.perm_read This code will return True

Comment: do not use @ in the if  ==> if (item.perm_read == true)

Comment: I tried as you said. I traced. after comparing control will go to opening flower brace then next control will go to close flower bracket. Whatever comes in between of flower brackets, nothing executes

Comment: Nothing executes inside the if statement. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked value of @item.perm_read is  true or "true"

Comment: you cannot debug inside the flower brace as you say beacuse its HTML and not c# code. even though you are assigning values to the HTML you cannot debug at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (c3card.Dal.EDModel.tm_scrn_screen obj in tmgrp)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @obj.scrn_name
    </td>
</tr>


foreach (var item in ViewBag.perm_details)
{
    if (obj.scrn_id == @item.scrn_id)
    {
        <tr> <td>@item.perm_read</td></tr>
        <tr> <td>@item.perm_write</td></tr>

        if (item.perm_read == true)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber1" checked="checked" />
                </td>
                }
                else
                {
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        if (item.perm_write == true)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber1" checked="checked" />
                </td>
                }
                else
                {
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber2" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" title="@obj.scrn_id" value="@obj.scrn_id" class="chkNumber2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

}
```

}

you should not be using  if(@item.perm_read == true)

it must be if(item.perm_read == true)  you should remove @ in if statement

I still wonder normally either you must try with @if(item.perm_read == true)  or if(item.perm_read == true) as you preceding statements have c# code it must need to throw error.